# Can I change the Microsoft account I'm using for Visual Studio after creating a developer's license?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I want to create Metro apps for Windows 8, and I have VS 2012, but I need a developer's license. If I use fake credentials, will I be able to later get a different developer's license with a different Microsoft account on the same computer?

If I can change it later, how?

Comment: To the downvoter, could you at least tell me what's wrong with my question?

Comment: I would discourage you from using "fake credentials".  But no, the "name police" aren't going to come knocking at your door.  You will be able to get a different account, and you will be able to use the same computer :)

Comment: @paulsm4 I wasn't worried about the "name police", but I want to know that if I want to later put it on the store, I'll be able to change the account on my developer's license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The developer account you are entering can be as far as I know independent to the real account you will use for publishing your apps.
Every time you want to create app package for uploading you're entering your credentials, in case you want to develop under several different accounts, so yes, there should be no problem when using different account for "activating Windows 8 development" and for publishing your apps.

Comment: Thanks, I'm at least confident enough to try now. I'll accept after I test it.